# how to write and read xml string to aws? I am using pustream and getstream call for the same

Tags: c#, stream

I used aws.putStream to strore xml string and aws.getstream to get the content and read.
I get amazon.util.internal.hashstream at position error when I run getstream.

get the file - at the following like i see amazon.... stream at position error

```
Stream fileStream = _AWS.GetStream(filepath);
```

I try to read to the stream and get the error - cannot read stream

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Debug.WriteLine(fileStream.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What are your variables `aws` or `_AWS`. I am assuming you are using some kind of AWS client SDK? Which AWS service are we talking about? S3?

Comment: I am using aws sdk client apis for getstream and putstream. Basically I have a Xelement value which I want to store and retrieve it and decode when needed. I have tried to store it in String variable and then to a json which changed the content with whitespaces. I am open for other options as well.